# PHP separate Foreach loop values and store to variables

Tags: php

Hello I have an array and a foreach loop, which is technically working fine. Here is my code.

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $data['manrat'][] = array(
        'manufacturer' => $result['manufacturer'],
        'mhref'        => $this->url->link('/info', 'manufacturer_id=' . $result['manufacturer_id'])
    );
}
```

And

```
<?php foreach($manrat as $manrate) { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $manrate['mhref']; ?>"><?php echo $manrate['manufacturer'];?> </a>
<?php } ?>
```

This is give me a result like this:

```
name1 name2 name3 name4 name5
```

I would like to store each name to different variables. This is possible?

Comment: Yes. But what's the logic of it? Do you really need separate variables for whatever you are trying to do?

Comment: I need to use them later, display in a highchart. I use highchart.js and there I have to set the names for each column. But the names are coming from database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't quite understand your question properly but if this is what you mean, then here's my answer. You can just store to different variable or an array like names[] by adding the assigning code in your loop like:

```
<?php
$names = array();
foreach($manrat as $manrate) {
 $names[] = $manrate['manufacturer'];
}
?>
```

You can then get the names as elements of the array like: $names[0], $names[1], ... etc.

I hope this answered your question.

Comment: Sorry, maybe my question is not was clear. But this is exactly what I looking for. Thank you!

Comment: [array_columns()](http://php.net/array_columns) does all that in a single line of code...

Answer (score 0):

I would refactor this code into one foreach loop like this:

```
$anchors = '';

foreach ($results as $result) {
    $anchors .= '<a href="' . $this->url->link('/info', 'manufacturer_id=' . $result['manufacturer_id']) . '">' . $result['manufacturer'] . '</a>';
}
```

and on your actual HTML output page:

```
<?php echo $anchors ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use **implode** and if you want turn String to Array use **explode**

```
$array_to_string = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'];
$store_to_string =  implode(',',$array_to_string ); // a,b,c,d,e,f,g
```